# Naming ivar the same as the class name

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I've never considered this a problem, until I ran the Xcode "Analyze" feature. Say I have a class called `dude` and I have created an instance of class and synthesized it so `self.dude` is available.

This works just fine. However, in the `dealloc` if I put:

```
 [self.dude release];
```

I get an Analyzer warning because really what it should be is:

```
[dude release];
```

However, this spawns another warning, as Analyzer thinks I am sending the `release` to the class name, not to the ivar.

Now, if the ivar is named something different than the class, there is no problem and `[ivar release];` works without Analyzer warnings.

Should I take this as a general indication that it is not wise to name an ivar the same as a class name? It has never interfered with my product compilation or execution, but the Analyzer opens new questions about this.

Comment: By convention class names start with a capital letter and variables start with a lower case letter. You shouldn't have a problem if you follow this convention.

Comment: you should not really call release on the property as its not really the ivar. it could be a copy or already added to an autoreleasepool with the [[var retain] autorelease] paradigm, should call the ivar directly `[dude release]` .

Comment: @bigkm There's a big debate which of `self.dude=nil` and `[dude release]` is better :p

Comment: @Yuji thats not what i was talking about, i hit enter accidentally and had to finish my comment.

Comment: @bibkm Ah, I see. `[self.dude release]` is definitely wrong, I agree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should start you class names with uppercase letters (`Dude`) and instance variables (and other variables for that matter) with lower case letters (`dude`). This avoids the problem entirely and you'd also be following the standard naming conventions for Objective-C.

Comment: interesting that the Apple templates begin the class names with lowercase laters, such as `projectViewController.m'

Comment: @andrewx - where have you seen this? They may name an _instance_ of a class projectViewController, but not the class itself

Comment: i was referring to the custom subclass of the view controller in the single view template; but now I realize it just takes your project name as the subclass name

Answer (score 0):

It definitely is not a common practice to start a class name with a lower case letter. Objective-C/Cocoa convention is that you start a class name with a capital, and the method name and the instance variable name with a lower case letter.

Just follow the common practice and name your class `Dude` and name your ivar `dude`.